# using an undefined amount of checkboxes to add to database

Tags: php, html, sql, checkbox

**This is my form:**

```
<form action="toevoegen.php" method="post">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="leerlingnr" name="leerlingnr">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="leerlingnr">Leerlingnr</label>
        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">dit is geen leerlingnummer.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="inleverdatum" name="inleverdatum">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inleverdatum">Inleverdatum</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        foreach($producten as $row)
        {
            echo("
            <label class='mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect' for='checkbox-" . $counter ."'>
                <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='name-" . $counter ."' value='$counter'>
                <span class='mdl-checkbox__label'>" . $row['productcode'] . ' ' . $row['categorie'] . ' ' . $row['merk'] . ' ' . $row['type'] . ' ' . $row['cpu'] . ' ' . $row['ram'] . ' ' . $row['os'] . ' ' . $row['hdd'] . ' ' ."</span>
            </label>
            ");
            $counter++;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

this outputs all the information about the products in a checkbox list, like on this printscreen: https://gyazo.com/719522a3c473a0d0c5c11f1535d20683

how would I be able to use these checkboxes to add them to a final invoice and into the table 'invoice'?

```
 include_once("connection.php");
 $llnr = $_POST['leerlingnr'];
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
 $leendatum = date('d-m-Y');
 $inleverdatum = $_POST["inleverdatum"];
 echo $llnr . "<br/>";
 echo $leendatum . "<br/>";
 echo $inleverdatum . "<br/>";
```

this is the code I have righ now, but it's only to add some extra data to the database for registration.

Comment: You can use array as name `name='checkbox[]'` then just check witch values it holds

Comment: @BogdanKuštan I'm not sure what you mean with that, could you explain a bit further?

Comment: try changing the name of the checkbox in your loop like an array. `name="chck_box_name[]"` and get its value by `$_POST['chck_box_name']`

Comment: `                <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-" . $counter ."' class='mdl-checkbox__input' name='checkbox[]' value='$counter'>
` it will be available in Your $_POST array

Comment: @BogdanKuštan so if I understand correctly, this adds the value of `$counter` to the array of `$checkbox[]`?